# What is the point of specifying aquatic in "aquatic swimming"?

Tags: adjectives

I read on https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2021/jul/02/swimming-caps-for-natural-black-hair-ruled-out-of-olympic-games-alice-dearing ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210703040530/https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2021/jul/02/swimming-caps-for-natural-black-hair-ruled-out-of-olympic-games-alice-dearing)):

> Aquatic swimming must do better.

I see "aquatic swimming" being used in quite a few other places as well:

[image]

What is the point of specifying aquatic in "aquatic swimming"?

Comment: To me it seems redundant, nay, superfluous, pleonastic and supernumerary, to say nothing of tautological. Though there are *non-aquatic* swimming simulations, e.g., https://totalgymdirect.com/total-gym-blog/replicate-swimming-exercises-using-total-gym , "swimming" is by nature one of the aquatic sports.

Comment: It's also redundant

Comment: ...and redundant. (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no the point in specifying aquatic in “aquatic swimming” according to the comment section:

> - To me it seems redundant, nay, superfluous, pleonastic and supernumerary, to say nothing of tautological. Though there are *non-aquatic* swimming simulations, e.g., [totalgymdirect.com/total-gym-blog/…](https://totalgymdirect.com/total-gym-blog/replicate-swimming-exercises-using-total-gym) , "swimming" is by nature one of the aquatic sports. – [DrMoishe Pippik](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13999/drmoishe-pippik) [Jul 4 at 2:42](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290499/what-is-the-point-of-specifying-aquatic-in-aquatic-swimming#comment541598_290499)
> - It's also redundant – [gotube](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113306/gotube) [Jul 4 at 7:06](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290499/what-is-the-point-of-specifying-aquatic-in-aquatic-swimming#comment541615_290499)
> - ...and redundant. (Sorry, couldn't resist.) – [Divizna](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/138126/divizna) [Jul 4 at 12:29](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290499/what-is-the-point-of-specifying-aquatic-in-aquatic-swimming#comment541644_290499)

Comment: While sea water is water and marine swimming is an aquatic activity, I wonder whether a distinction is drawn between aquatic swimming and sea swimming.

Comment: If it is any help Alice Dearing mentioned in the article is an open water swimmer. Perhaps that is what it means as opposed to swimming in a pool.